# how do I mock sqlconnection or should I refactor the code?

Tags: unit-testing, ado.net, moq, xunit, sqlconnection

I have the code below, I have read [Moq and SqlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944462/moq-and-sqlconnection)  and [How can I stub IDBconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976826/how-can-i-stub-idbconnection), but I still have no idea how to mock the following sqlconnection.

```cs
public class SqlBulkWriter : ISqlBulkWriter
{
    private readonly string _dbConnectionString;;

    public SqlBulkWriter(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        this._dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    public void EmptyTable(string schema, string tableName)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this._dbConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var truncate = new SqlCommand($"TRUNCATE TABLE [{schema}].[{tableName}] ", connection))
                {
                    truncate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to do the unit test for EmptyTable, I think I should mock the sqlconnection firstly? or how do I do the unit test for the EmptyTempTable?

Thank you! Many appreciate!

Comment: is this testable? or should I refactor the code? if so, how do I refactor the code? Thank you!

Comment: You are tightly coupling your code to implementation concerns. consider using the abstractions and injecting them into the class.

Comment: okay. I changed a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SqlBulkWriter` class is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which make it difficult to test the class in isolation.

Knowing the connection string is not really a concern of that class and can be delegated out to another service.

Something like

```cs
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
   IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

and its implementation for your class would look something like this

```cs
public class SqlConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory {
    private readonly string dbConnectionString;

    public SqlConnectionFactory(string dbConnectionString) {
        this.dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() {
        return new SqlConnection(this.dbConnectionString);
    }
}
```

`SqlBulkWriter` class can now be refactored to depend on the abstraction instead of the concretion.

```cs
public class SqlBulkWriter : ISqlBulkWriter {
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public SqlBulkWriter(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public void EmptyTable(string schema, string tableName) {
        using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection()) {
            try {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                    command.CommandText = $"TRUNCATE TABLE [{schema}].[{tableName}] ";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the class to easier to be tested in isolation as those abstractions can be mocked and injected into the class.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class SqlBulkWriter_Should {
    [TestMethod]
    public void EmptyTable() {
        //Arrange
        var mock = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
        var command = mock.OneOf<IDbCommand>();
        var connection = mock.OneOf<IDbConnection>(_ => _.CreateCommand() == command);
        var factory = mock.OneOf<IDbConnectionFactory>(_ => _.CreateConnection() == connection);

        var subject = new SqlBulkWriter(factory);
        var schema = "dbo";
        var tableName = "TestTable";

        //Act
        subject.EmptyTable(schema, tableName);

        //Assert
        Mock.Get(command).Verify(_ => _.ExecuteNonQuery(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework.

Comment: THanks a lot. you are my hero